# PHP multiple Dropdown list, not passing arrayto foreach() PHP newbie

Tags: php, windows

```
services = $row['services_provided'];//services is in the projects table,  cmt_services

<select name="services" multiple> <?php
dbConnect();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cmt_services order servicesid");
while ($result2=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$Selectedservice="";
if (is_array($s_p)){
foreach ($services as $key=> $value) {
if ($result2['servicesid']==$value) 
{
    $Selectedservice = "selected";}
}
echo '<option value="'.$result2['servicesid'].'"'.$SelectedBus.'>'.$result2['service_name'].'    '.$SelectedBus.'</option>';
        }
}?>
</select>    
//
```

Dropdown populates using data in cmt_services stored in project table using servicesid as 1,2,3. How can I display 1,2,3 as selected among 1,2,3,4,5,6?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick in PHP where you use square-braces to tell PHP to expect an array:

```
<select name="services[]" multiple>
```

You should now find that you automatically have an array from your request.

```
$services = $_POST['services']; // this is an array
```

Comment: just tried  <select name="services[]" multiple> and still the list shows an empty box

Comment: What do you see if you use `print_r($services);` just after `$services = $row['services_provided'];`